# expresión aritmética

Tags: java

ejercicio : `(x^2-4x+4)/4  ((2x+1 )/2x  + (x^2+x+2)/(2x^2-4x)  - 3/2)^2`
lo que tengo yo:

```
lic static void main(String[] args) {
    double a, b, c, d, x,result; 
    
    a = 4;
    b = 2;
    c = 1;
    d = 3/2;
    
    
    x = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el valor de x"));
    
    
    result = Math.pow((x),2) - a * x + a / a * Math.pow((b * x + c / 2 * x +Math.pow((x),2) 
    + x + b / b * Math.pow((x),2) - a * x - c ),2);
    
    
   
    
    
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El resultado de la expresion es"+result);
```

se supone que cuando lo corra e inserte el valor de X me debería dar 1 pero no es así no se si me falta algo o que, ya revise hasta hice la operacion por separado y no me da el resultado que deberia

Comment: Resuelve la primero a mano con lápiz y papel y despues implementa el algoritmo en la pc

Comment: ya lo hice y si me da 1, me falto agregar que X debe tomar el valor de 3

Comment: No es necesario sustituir los valores constantes en la fórmula por más variables. Puedes dejar valores constantes. Ten cuidado de no alterar la precedencia de los operadores. Por ejemplo, en la fórmula, al inicio, es todo el trinomio el que está dividido entre 4, y en tu código, el único número que se divide entre 4 es 4 (la variable `a`), ya que has quitado los paréntesis. Eso mismo te sigue pasando más adelante...

Comment: Ten cuidado en la _traducción_ de la expresión `/2x`, pues si lo cambias simplemente por `/2*x` divides entre dos y el resultado lo multiplicas por `x`. El lenguaje de programación exige allí introducir un paréntesis para mantener la precedencia correcta de los operadores, ya que como humanos entendemos perfectamente que se quiere dividir entre `2x`, lo correcto es poner `/(2*x)`, para que el compilador lo entienda igual.

Comment: Okeeey, no sabia lo de los paréntesis ya entiendo todo, muchas gracias. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que algo le falta a tu expresión original... Si revisas la gráfica de lo que se entiende de tu expresión no se acerca al 1 cuando x=3
https://www.geogebra.org/graphing/uw6rgved
Y bueno, como mencionan arriba, no es necesario que guardes el valor de tus constantes numéricas, a menos que sean 'parámetros' que vas a mover en algún momento. En este caso:

```
result = (Math.pow(x, 2) - 4*x + 4 ) / ( 4 * ( ((2*x+1)/(2*x)) +
                Math.pow(( (Math.pow(x, 2) + x + 2)/((Math.pow(x, 2) - 4*x)) - (3/2) ),2) ));
```